# jqgrid display static column that not in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there any way to display a static column value ( ex - "ClickHere" will display in the all rows with the "Details" as column header) in `Jqgrid`? i am using `spring MVC` `Jackson` support for populate the `jqgrid` by using a `jsonReader`. i just need to have a static string as a column that not comes with the `JSON`.

Ex -

`Student Name`  | `Detail` |

---

```
  XXXX  | clickhere
  YYYY  | clickhere
```

I need to have 'clickHere' string hardcoded in a jqgrid column while i used studentName from the json object. Can this is doable?

Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use spring MVC myself, but to create a column with the static text 'Click here' you can define it with respect of [the custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter):

```
{ name:'Details', width:60, sortable:false, search:false,
  formatter:function(){
      return 'Click here';
  },
  unformatter:function(){return '';}
}
```

The definition of the `unformatter` is optional. Probably you will not need it. It's depend on how you read (it you ever do it) the data from grid.

It can be that [formatter:'showlink'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) of some other form of link is what you really want to do. In the case you can find the answer on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010761/linking-from-a-column-value-in-jqgrid-to-a-new-page-using-get/5017528#5017528) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UnobtrusiveLinks1.htm)).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. i found one of your [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomLink.htm) here. it was also really helpfull. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sam: You are welcome! Yes, the old demo use the same idea, but it was written before. It uses `getDataIDs` and then `$("#"+ids[i]+" a",myGridNode);` in the loop which could be slow in case of large grid. Now I would rewrote the statement at least to `$("a:first",gridRows.namedItem(ids[i]));` where `var gridRows = myGridNode.rows;` are defined above the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ name:function(){return 'Click here';},
  width:60, sortable:false, search:false,
  formatter:'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:', showAction: "somefunction('", addParam: "');"}      
}
```

By using this way u can use all other option as well like formatoptions