# Add a hyperlink in one of the columns in JQGrid and clicking on Hyperlink should open a new window

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with certain columns and I need hyperlink in one of the columns, clicking on the hyperlink should open a new window, basically call a window.open().

Also when I call the window.open(), I need the hyperlink column value.
Please provide me with some sample code.Anyhelp would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Oleg, I tried the below code and it is throwing error "object expected" in load().

```
 {name:'FileName', FileName:'price', width:60, align:"center", formatter:returnMyLink}

    function returnMyLink(cellValue, options, rowdata) 
     {  
             return "<a href='javascript:load();'>Open Window</a>";

     }
     function load() 
      {
         var guid = 'CEF9C407-2500-4619-95E3-8E6227B65954';
  window.open              ('/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.medline.medpack.ExcelViewerPL.ExcelViewer?report=CustomerBenefit&reportId='+guid );
       }
```

I did try the document.delegate to capture the a href event.

```
$(document).delegate('#CustomerSavingsView .jqgrow td a[href="#"]', 'click',function()
  {
     alert('test');
  }
```

I was not able to capture this event either.
   Sorry Im new to Jquery. Please correct me if Im wrong.

Thanks

This is how I solved it. In the grid complete event added the following code.

```
      hl = "<a href='#Test' target='_blank' id='hlink"+cl+"'>Test</a>";
```

And then added a event handler for it.

```
$(document).delegate('#CustomerSavingsView .jqgrow td a[href*="#Test"]', 'click',  function () 
 { 

     var guid = 'CEF9C407-2500-4619-95E3-8E6227B65954';
   window.open('/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.medline.medpack.ExcelViewerPL.ExcelViewer?report=CustomerBenefit&reportId='+guid );
 }
```

This solved the purpose. Thanks again Oleg and Walter.

Comment: "Also when I call the window.open(), I need the hyperlink column value", are you saying that you want to pass the value from the column to the new window?

Comment: Yes I need to pass the value of the column to the new window.

Answer (score 4):

maybe this will be help:
in colModel,define a col: `{name:'test',formatter:linkformatter}`
and in javascript create a function named linkformatter which returns a link;
like:

```
function linkformatter( cellvalue, options, rowObject){
  return '<a href='xxxxxx' />';
}
```

Comment: lycatliu, I tried this custom formatter. This does not work for me, since I need to call window.open on href. The above code will navigate me to a different URL in the same page.

Comment: change it to  return '<a href='xxxxxx' target="_blank" />'; However, target="_blank" is deprecated in newer versions of HTML.

Comment: Thanks Walter and Oleg. But I solved it in a different way. Please find the way I did.

Answer (score 2):

The [predefined formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) `'showlink'` can be used to create the link in the grid column. You can use `target` property of the `formatoptions` options to define [target](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-frame-target) of the link.

Comment: Oleg, I learn something new about jqGrid every time I read one of your responses. This is cleaner than my current solution. I've been using a custom formatter to render the hyperlinks, with an attached event handler that calls window.open() .

However, I have one question or you: is there a way to define the value of the url parameter? It defaults to the row-index, but I want the cellvalue.

Comment: Oleg, I tried a custom formatter and even with that I wasnt able to achieve my task. Please see my code .

Comment: @WalterStabosz: The standard 'showlink' has do restricted functionality. For example you can't place `cellvalue` in the another place or place the rowid as the part of url (like `edit/123` and not `edit?id=123`). I would prefer to be able to define `baseLinkUrl` or just `url` as the function and defines if myself. You can currently continue to use custom formatter in your case or you can use `cellattr` to define `onclick` attribute or you can use Unobtrusive links like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5017528/315935)

Comment: @Oleg - The Unobtrusive links might not work for me, since I need to open a new window on href click. The code creates a href on grid complete event which might not be helpful. I would like to go for Custom formatter, since I can get the value of the cell, but Im not sure how to open a new window on href click.

Comment: @sivshan: In case of unobtrusive links your JavaScript code will be executed. So you can do all what you want. For example you can use `window.open` (choose the value of the second parameter like you want).

Answer (score 1):

First declare the Jquery JQGrid column definition as follows

```
   colModel: [{ name: 'Notes/Memos', width: "5", sortable: true, classes: 'ellip', resizable: false, formatter: MethodFormatter }]
```

The formatter property takes the method name which is invoked with the three parameters which internally having the cells value and its id and the following method returns the hyperlink.

```
       function MethodFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
            var selectedRowId = options.rowId;
            return '<a href="javascript:MethodJS(' + selectedRowId + ')" style="color: #3366ff" id="' + selectedRowId + '" >' + cellValue + '</a>';}
```

The following JS Function is invoked after clicking the hyperlink which opens up another page in a window.

```
       function MethodJS(selectedRowId) {
    document.location.href = "ViewContact.aspx?NoteID=" + selectedRowId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach involves fewer lines of code and gives the solution asked for.  In my grid, a column called Project Number is formatted as a hyper link.  It opens a new page and passes the project number as a parameter.

```
colNames: ["Project #", ...],

colModel: [ 
              { name: 'Project Number', index: 'Project Number', width: 80, key: true, formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'Details.aspx', target: '_new' } },
```

Note where I have key: true.  Without this, the url returns the row number.  The url returned is http://localhost:57631/Details.aspx?id=2103

[image: Clicking on the project number in the grid]

[image: Details page opened in new window]

I'm using jqGrid version 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This is my pattern. As I said, it is much more code than Oleg's suggestion of using the showlink formatter, but it is more customizable.

```
 // bind a live event handler to any elements matching the selector 'a.linkWindowOpener'
 $('a.linkWindowOpener').live('click', linkWindowOpener);

// colModel settings
    { name: 'ItemDescription', index: 'ItemDescription', formatter: itemDescription_formatter, unformat: itemDescription_unformatter }, 

// custom formatter to create the hyperlink 
function itemDescription_formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

    var html = '';
    var itemID = rowObject.itemID;
    var itemDescription = cellvalue;

    var a = $('<a>')
            .attr('href', '/Forms/WorkOrder/ViewItem.aspx?ItemID=' + itemID)
            .attr('data-itemDescription', itemDescription )
            .html(itemDescription)
            .addClass('linkWindowOpener');

    html = a.getHtml();

    return html;
}

// unformatter to return the raw value
function itemDescription_unformatter( cellvalue, options, cell) {
    return $('a', cell).attr('data-itemDescription');
}

// event handler to call when clicking the hyperlink
function linkWindowOpener(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var o = $(event.currentTarget);
    var url = o.attr('href');
    window.open(url);
    return false;
}

// jQuery extenision function I wrote to get the HTML of an element
// returns the HTML of an element. It works by wrapping the element 
// inside a DIV and calling DIV.html(). It then returns the element back to 
// it's original DOM location
jQuery.fn.getHtml = function () {

    var elm = $(this[0]);
    // create a div
    var div = $('<div>');

    // append it to the parent of the target element
    elm.parent().append(div);
    // append the element to the div
    div.append(elm);

    // get the html of the div
    var html = div.html();

    // move element back to its parent
    div.parent().append(elm);
    div.remove();

    return html;
}
```