# How do you retrieve selected cell value in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

With the code below, it displays the cell value that was last selected. How do I display the cell value of the row I just clicked on?

```
jQuery('#grid').click( function() {
  var grid = jQuery('#grid);
  var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
  var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'source_id');
  $('#selrow').html("Source ID selected:" + myCellData);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is a little strange because you use jQuery binding to `click` instead of the usage of events like [onCellSelect](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events). If you use this you should use the first parameter of the click function, for example `e` (`jQuery('#grid').click(function(e) {...});`). The `e.target` is the DOM element of the cell (`<td>`) or an element inside of cell (like `<a>` inside of `<td>`) which the user clicked. The code `$(e.target).closest("td")` will gives you the cell.

If you do decide to use [onCellSelect](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) I would recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303471/browser-memory-usage-comparison-inline-onclick-vs-using-jquery-bind/5305904#5305904) with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CellClick.htm).

Answer (score 1):

When setting up the grid, you can define a callback function for the onCellSelect event.

e.g:

```
var grid = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid( {
 ... default grid setup ...,
 onCellSelect: function(rowid, icol, cellcontent, e) { alert(cellcontent); },
 });
```

A list of all the jqGrid events is here:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events