# Add an icon instead of a text in a column

Tags: jqgrid

in JQGrid 3.8, is it possible to have an icon instead of text in a column ?

I don't think it's possible but if you have a trick, i'd be happy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to add icons in the grid. First way is: the data which be placed in the column header (`colNames`) or inside of the cell data could be HTML data. So you can easy insert the `<img>` element in the grid. One more method is th use [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303471/browser-memory-usage-comparison-inline-onclick-vs-using-jquery-bind/5305904#5305904) some demos. If  [the standard jQuery UI icons](http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/jqueryui-icons/) contain all the icons which you need I would recommend you to use there.