# I could not able to see Add. Edit, Delete and View using JQGrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/TabMaster/GetGridData',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['col ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', '', '', '', ''],
            colModel: [
                  { name: 'colID', index: 'colID', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 150, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 300, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'add', width: 18, sortable: false, search: false,
                      formatter: function () {
                          return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-plus'></span>"
                      }
                  },
                  { name: 'edit', width: 18, sortable: false, search: false,
                      formatter: function () {
                          return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil'></span>"
                      }
                  },
                  { name: 'del', width: 18, sortable: false, search: false,
                      formatter: function () {
                          return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"
                      }
                  },
                  { name: 'details', width: 18, sortable: false, search: false,
                      formatter: function () {
                          return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-document'></span>"
                      }
                  }
                ],
            onSelectRow: function (rowJsonId)
            { handleSelectedRow(rowJsonId); },
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 4,
            rowList: [1, 2, 4, 5, 10],
            sortname: 'colID',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            multiselect: true,
            imgpath: '/scripts/themes/steel/images',
            caption: 'Tab Master Information'
        }).navGrid(pager, { edit: true, add: true, del: true, refresh: true, search: true });
    });

    function handleSelectedRow(thing) {
    }
```

but i could not able to see buttons for **Add, Edit, Delete and View** i am only able to see for empty column in JQGrid.
for your reference 
[image: I am not able to see ADD, EDIT, DELETE and VIEW]

Please provide your valuable comments for the same.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you try to use [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CellClick.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303471/browser-memory-usage-comparison-inline-onclick-vs-using-jquery-bind/5305904#5305904):

[image]

All classes for the `ui-icon-plus`, `ui-icon-trash` and so on come from jQuery UI CSS. You shoul just verify that you included jQuery UI correctly together with the `images` subdirectory.

Comment: I have verified all the CSS and Images are there and i have also added reference of it.

Comment: @imdadhusen: It **must be** a difference. My demo works. If your demo are accessible from the internet you can post the URL. If not you can upload your demo project and post the URL.

Comment: @imdadhusen: I have no idea. I have my web server. You should search in Internet for any free data upload server.

Comment: Thanks for valuable suggestion!

Comment: @imdadhusen: I know that there are many places in the internet where you can upload the data. Just use google. I can help you only in the subject where I have more know-how or experience as you, but if I not know something I just write this.

Comment: @imdadhusen: You can post the project to oleg.kiriljuk@ok-soft-gmbh.com if you have still problems to find the place to uploading of the test project.