# In a jqGrid, how can I get the row that another element is in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have a `jqGrid` which has a column called "Actions".  In this column, each row has a number of buttons which are supposed to perform various functions on the data in that row.

Unfortunately, the only grid parameter I've found that remotely matches what I want to do is `selrow`.  This gets the *selected* row.  But if the user clicks one of the action buttons, this doesn't necessarily mean that row is "selected" (i.e., the user has clicked on it previously).

Is there a way I can get the row of the button the user presses?  Or does it not make sense to have buttons inside of the `jqGrid` to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use for example `onCellSelect` to detect which button is clicked you will have directly the `rowid` of the button which is clicked. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305904/315935) will get you more details about the implementation.

If you would prefer to implement custom `click` event handler you can just find the closest `<tr>` element. It's `id` is the rowid of the clicked button. So you can use something like `$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")` where `e` is the event of the `click` handler.