# jqgrid link on select row overrides formatter link

Tags: jqgrid, onselect

The onselectRow link works, but it overrides the formatter link.

If I comment out the OnSelect location, the formatter link works.  Otherwise, the formatter link doesn't work.  Anyway around that?

thanks

```
onSelectRow: function(row_id) {
location.href="/blah/"+aId;
},
```

But if it's enabled, it overrides this link:

```
{name:'ID',index:'ID',formatter:pbf, width: 90,align: "center", fixed: true,sortable:false,resizable:false}

gridComplete: function() {
        $('span[name="pay"]').click(function() {
    location.href='/ew/'+ad;              
     }


function pbf(cellvalue, options, rowObject){    
var pay = '<span name="pay" id="'+rowObject.ID+'" class="ui-icon ui-icon-check" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: -3px; float: left"></span>';
   return pay;
```

}

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Setting `window.location.href` in both `onSelectRow` and `$('span[name="pay"]').click` has no sense. Probably you need something like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935)? You can use either `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` to implement `click` callback **without** binding `click` handler to `span` of every cell in the column. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5305904/315935) for some additional information.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I have icons in the last cell, and they each have distinct links.  But I want all the rest of the row to have its own separate link.  But I guess by design the     onSelectRow overrides the icons links, as they are in the row.

Comment: You are welcome! I hope it will help you.