# How do I configure a jquery "selector" to limit "change" event detection to a specific "<table>" in an HTML document?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am attempting to use jquery to detect checkbox changes in a specific table (i.e., "grid1").

*(FWIW - the table is a jqgrid)*

But, it appears that the "selector" statement I am using is not working the way I expect.

Instead of detecting checkbox changes within the specific table (i.e., "grid1"),  it is also detecting/reacting to changes in the entire document - including "grid2".

I am clearly doing something wrong with my selector.  --I just don't know what.

Thanks for any help on this   :-)

FYI - The jquery "selector" code looks like this...

```
        $("#grid1 :checkbox")
        {
            $(this).change( function(e)
            {
                var t = $(e.target);   
                var row = t.closest("tbody").children().index(t.closest("tr"));
                var rowids = $('#grid1').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                var rowid = rowids[row-1];
                var rowdata = $("#grid1").getRowData(rowid);
                $("#grid1").jqGrid('setRowData', rowid, rowdata); 
                $("#grid1").setSelection(rowid);                        
            });
        };
```

...and the HTML structure that looks like this...

```
        <body>
            <form id="form1">
                <div>
                    <div>                    
                        <input type="submit" id="submit"  value="Submit Grid Edits" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="div1">
                        <table id="grid1"></table>
                        <div id="pager1" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div2">
                        <table id="grid2"></table>
                        <div id="pager2" ></div>
                    </div>                
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
```

Comment: Your first two lines look invalid, should be throwing a js error.

Comment: Do you use `formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled: false}` or some other custom formatter with chechbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
    $("#grid1 :checkbox").on("change", function(e) {
        //do stuff
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pR29M/)

**EDIT:**

As both @sairn and @Oleg mentioned, this would be more appropriate:

```
$("#grid1").on("change", ":checkbox", function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: You're right JayPea!.. - Ironically, I had just discovered the solution a few mins ago, myself. (Thank you very much for reading AND answering my post)... I had used: $("#grid1").on('change','input:checkbox', function (e){}

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to bind `"change"` event on `<table>` element instead of usage `$("#grid1 :checkbox").on("change", ...);`. The main difference is that `$("#grid1 :checkbox")` represent array of checkboxes. and binding will set **separate** event handles on every of the element. On the other side if you bind `change` event of `<table>` you set **only one** event handle. Because of [event bubbling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_flow) we can catch in the event handler `"change"` event fired by child checkboxes. In the way you save a little memory needed to register every handle, but your code will be still very simple. See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305904/315935) which discuss close problems.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DetectChangeOfCheckbox.htm) demonstrate the approach. The event handle looks so

```js
$("#grid1").change(function (e) {
    var $td = $(e.target).closest("td"),     // the cell
        $tr = $td.closest("tr.jqgrow"),      // the row
        rowid = $tr.attr("id"),
        iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]), // column index
        colModel = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");

    // verify that event fired in the column "closed"
    if (iCol >= 0 && colModel[iCol].name === "closed" &&
            e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT") {
        alert("Chechbox in rowid=" + rowid + " clicked. It's " +
            ($(e.target).is(":checked") ? "checked" : "unchecked") + " now");
    }
});
```

It displays results like the following

[image]